# Take Variables Set in Functions.php and Echo Them Inside My Custom Post Template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, page-template, variables

I have the following function set up in my functions.php file to allow my custom post type "Slideshow" to work.

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'paginate_slide' );

function paginate_slide( $post ) {

    global $pages, $multipage, $numpages;

    if( is_single() && get_post_type() == 'lom_slideshow' ) {
    $prefix = "slide{$i}";
    $multipage = 1;
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $custom = array();
    $pages = array();
    $i = 1;

    foreach( get_post_custom_keys() as $key )
        if ( false !== strpos( $key, 'slide' ) )
            $custom[$key] = get_post_meta( $id, $key, true);

    while( isset( $custom["slide{$i}-title"] ) ) {

    $hide = $custom["slide{$i}-hide"];
    $slidetype = $custom["slide{$i}-slidetype"];

    if( 'on' == $hide ) {
    $i++;
    continue;
                        }

        $page = '';
        $title = $custom["slide{$i}-title"];
        $image = $custom["slide{$i}-image"];
        $desc = $custom["slide{$i}-desc"];
        $embed = $custom["slide{$i}-embed"];
        if(isset($image))
        $imgdisplay = "<img src='{$image}' />";
        else
        $imgdisplay = '';

    if( 'Video' == $slidetype ) 

        $page = "<div class='media-title'><h2>{$title}</h2></div><div class='media-image'>{$embed}</div><div class='media-desc'></div>";
    else
        $page = "<div class='media-title'><h2>{$title}</h2></div><div class='media-image'>{$imgdisplay}</div><div class='media-desc'>{$desc}</div>";
        $pages[] = $page;
        $i++;
    }
    $numpages = count( $pages );
    }
}
```

This part displays the  output:

```
$page = "<div class='media-title'><h2>{$title}</h2></div><div class='media-image'>{$embed}</div><div class='media-desc'></div>";
```

It displays there where `the_content` is called in my template.  Rather than putting the pieces together there in my functions.php I'd like to be able to call each piece directly in my Custom Post template exactly where I want it.  For example, by putting `<?php echo $desc; ?>` in my template file where I want the Description to display and `<?php echo $title; ?>` where I want the Title to display.

I've tried a couple different ways but can't get anything to display.

**Without starting over from scratch or redesigning my whole template how can I make these variable more modular (able to be placed at will within my template)?**

Comment: I'd suggest having a little read on variable scope, see here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Thanks.  So I read through that and I thought it made sense but then I edited my code to define all the variables outside the function, then declare them as global inside the function but it still didn't work.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  (fyi, for that exercise I did make the variables a little more unique to avoid conflicts).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is look at your `$page` and `$pages` variables and do the same thing with your `$desc` variable (and any other variable that you want to access outside of the function).

You will need a global `$descs` which will be an array where you will place in each of the `$desc` values, using something like `$descs[] = $desc;` right after the code `$pages[] = $page;`. Then you would access `$descs` outside of the function, remember it is an array.

---

Usually, you need to declare `$desc` as a global in the template file you want to use it in, e.g. you need to use this:

```
<?php global $desc;
echo $desc;?>
```

It may be better to use a wrapping function that returns, or echos your `$desc` variable and call that from within your template file, e.g. place something like this in your functions.php:

```
function foo_bar()
{
$custom[$key] = get_post_meta( $id, $key, true);
return $custom["slide{$i}-desc"];
}
```

and then in your template file use this:

```
<?php echo foo_bar();?>
```

Note, this wrapping function won't work as is, since it looks like you grabbed something from within a PHP loop construct. You may need to pass in $id, $key, $i, and $custom to the function, or declare them as globals in the function. Without knowing the context, I can't tell you which way will work better for you.

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Which one? Adding the global declaration, or the wrapping function?

Comment: The wrapping function didin't work.  I didn't even see the example for the global, let me try that.

Comment: Just a note, the wrapping function won't work as is, since it looks like you grabbed something from within a PHP loop construct. You may need to pass in $id, $key, $i, and $custom to the function, or declare them as globals in the function.

Comment: Yes, the global code I provided should work by just copying it in and pasting it.

Comment: I know, I don't know how I missed that.  Sorry.

Comment: I wasn't able to get that to work.  I've updated my question with a lot more detail.  Would you mind taking a look again and see if that makes my problem more clear?

Comment: Wow, ok, with the new information, I can tell you my answer is way, way off. Will update it shortly.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: see my update, it briefly discusses what you need to do.