# How do I make my function add variables/values to the $post object?

Tags: php, functions, variables

How do I add `$tzDesc` and `$tzEmbed` (and other variables) to the `$post` object in the following function so that I can display the values in my theme files by inserting `<?php echo $tzDesc; ?>`?

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'paginate_slide' );

function paginate_slide( $post ) {

    global $pages, $multipage, $numpages;

    if( is_single() && get_post_type() == 'post' ) {

    $multipage = 1;
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $custom = array();
    $pages = array();
    $i = 1;

    foreach( get_post_custom_keys() as $key )
        if ( false !== strpos( $key, 'slide' ) )
            $custom[$key] = get_post_meta( $id, $key, true);

    while( isset( $custom["slide{$i}-title"] ) ) {

        $page = '';
        $tzTitle = $custom["slide{$i}-title"];
        $tzImage = $custom["slide{$i}-image"];
        $tzDesc = $custom["slide{$i}-desc"];
        $tzEmbed = $custom["slide{$i}-embed"];

        $page = "<h2>{$tzTitle}</h2><img src='{$tzImage}' />";
        $pages[] = $page;
        $i++;
    }

    $numpages = count( $pages );
    }
}
```

If you know and can provide an answer can you please be very detailed in how the code should be structured because my knowledge of php is very minimal and I have tried to do this numerous already without any success.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Like any other php object, you can add items to the $post object like so:

```
$post->my_new_val_name = 'my new value';
```

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but inside a function hooked to the_post, you can assign new values and return the object.

```
function my_func($post) {

    $post->my_new_val_name = 'my new value';
    return $post;

}
add_action( 'the_post', 'my_func' );
```

However, in your template file, you won't be able to just echo $my_new_val_name as you're suggesting... the the_post() function doesn't extract values that way. You'll have to reference the post object explicitly. Like:

```
echo $post->my_new_val_name;
```

Comment: I tried adding `$post->$tzEmbed = $custom["slide{$i}-embed"];` to the function above and I got an error: `Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in...`

Comment: My bad--had a typo in my answer. Leave the $ off of tzEmbed. Do $post->tzEmbed = $your_var;

Comment: That kind of worked. I put $post->tzEmbed = $custom["slide{$i}-embed"]; in my functions.php file then <?php echo $post->tzEmbed; ?> in my theme file, however it doesn't echo the correct information. The info is stored in the custom fields and the $i variable designates which one. So it should call from the custom field slide1-embed and slide2-embed... Instead its now displaying the contents of the very last slide (slide4-embed) for every slide. Is there any way to preserve the incremental nature of the $i variable?

Comment: Again, I'm really not sure exactly what you're doing here, but I guess you could store an array in $post->tzEmbed instead of a single value. Build an array containing each of your slide items, then add the array to the post object. $post->tzEmbed = array('myval1', 'myval2'); Then loop through it on the frontend. In any case, I think I've answered your original question, no?

Comment: I really do appreciate all your help, but no, I don't believe you have answered my original question: `How do I add $tzDesc and $tzEmbed (and other variables) to the $post object in the following function so that I can display the values in my theme files by inserting <?php echo $tzDesc; ?>?` because with your answer it doesn't correctly display the values for `$tzDesc` and `$tzEmbed`. If you look at my function `$tzDesc` is defined as `$tzDesc = $custom["slide{$i}-desc"];`  The `$custom` variable is getting passed along but for some reason it's losing the `$i`.

Comment: I feel like my last comment makes me sound like an ungrateful @$$ so I just want to reiterate I appreciate the input, and I realize I may not be asking the question correctly but I'm doing my best.  For a little background and context on what I'm trying to accomplish you can look [at this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4944/take-variables-set-in-functions-php-and-echo-them-inside-my-custom-post-template) and [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/help-creating-a-slideshow-custom-post-type-with-custom-meta-boxes).

Comment: My question is: what is the earliest wp hook that I should use to place properties in $post, so that it is available to other hooks and filters through out the life span of the page/request?